# React Hook "useSelector" used in common functions throws an error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

This is my **selectors.js**

`import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';`

`export const useCloseAlertTrigger = () => useSelector((state) => state.common.closeAlertTrigger || {});`

this is my **commonFunction.js** [in this I am storing my all common functions ]

```
export const LogoutUser = async () => {
  const closeAlert = useCloseAlertTrigger();
  if (closeAlert) {
    const result = await DisplayMessageOnClosebookingEdit();
    if (result) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  const result = await RCM_API(
    'POST',
    '',
    {
      service: 'service',
      action: 'logout',
    },
    true
  );
  if (result && result.resultCode === STATUS.SUCCESS) {
    window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/${BASE_PATH}/logout`;
  }
  return true;
};
```

in this functions I have used **useCloseAlertTrigger** hook but react throws an error that hook can be called inside functions it should called inside component only , and if I make simple functions rather than hook then another error arrives like useselctor can only be used inside component or react hook , that's why I have to give the prefix use

ps:sorry for poor english

i want to make the redux architecture common like i will make selectors functions inside selector.js and i will use that selectors in commonfunction.js and from that i will use respective function in component
PS: i am using **redux-toolkit **

Comment: React hooks can only be called in React function components and custom React hooks. `LogoutUser` is neither of these. See the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) for more detail. What exactly are you trying to do here? How are you expecting to use this `LogoutUser` function? Please [edit] to clarify the use case and provide a [mcve].

Comment: i want to use Logoutuser in my diff diff component (I do have 10 component) so I made one common function and exported it and I will use that in 10 components by directly importing it

Comment: Yes, please share an example how you wish to use `LogoutUser` function so it's clear to use what needs to be addressed in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you cannot use selectors in functions

```js
export const LogoutUser = async (closeAlert) => {
  if (closeAlert) {
    const result = await DisplayMessageOnClosebookingEdit();
    if (result) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  const result = await RCM_API(
    'POST',
    '',
    {
      service: 'service',
      action: 'logout',
    },
    true
  );
  if (result && result.resultCode === STATUS.SUCCESS) {
    window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/${BASE_PATH}/logout`;
  }
  return true;
};


// in the component
const closeAlert = useCloseAlertTrigger();

// whereever you call the logout function
LogoutUser(closeAlert)


// or use an useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  if (closeAlert) {
  LogoutUser(closeAlert)  
  }
},[closeAlert])
```